# How can I create a transparent tableview with each cells being transparent?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I tried all this inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
1.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
2.cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
3.cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

It only responds to the 1st line and makes the background a translucent kind of black. What should I do to get 100% transparency?

Comment: May be problem not in table view? Set tableView.hidden = YES; and look on screen. If you see white then problem not in table view.

Comment: I tried it with different views with different picture behind it. And I am using this as a popviewContoller.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same problem before.  As suggested in a comment, try `[setOpaque:NO]`

If push comes to shove, make a simple 1px clear .png.  Then, make a stretchable UIImage with it, and say `[setBackgroundView:imageViewWithClearImage]`.  That's a bit hacky, though.